# Event List returns empty array after a few calls to Google API via node.js

Tags: node.js, google-api, pagination, google-calendar-api

I'm using node for fetching a list of events with a date range.
I've seen there's a pagination limit within Google's API, however I'm looking for a way to get all events on the calendar each time the app runs.

This is what I've tried so far, but not luck with looping through the response pages from google.

```
const runSample = async () => {

    const pushDate = new Date("2019-12-22T08:28:19.593Z")
    const toDate = new Date()
    toDate.setDate(pushDate.getDate() + 3)
    let syncToken = null
    let pageToken = null
    const events = []

    const eventlist = await calendar.events.list({
        calendarId: '***_***@group.calendar.google.com',
        timeMin: pushDate,
        timeMax: toDate,
        showDeleted: false,
        singleEvents: true
    })
    events.push(eventlist.data.items)
    pageToken = await eventlist.data.nextPageToken

    while (pageToken != null) {
        let list = await calendar.events.list({
            calendarId: '***_***@group.calendar.google.com',
            nextPageToken: pageToken
        })
        events.push(list.data.items)
    }

    pageToken = await eventlist.data.nextPageToken
    syncToken = await eventlist.data.nextSyncToken

    const anotherlist = null

    console.log(events)

    console.log(syncToken)
    console.log(pageToken)

}

runSample().catch(console.error)
```

Is there a way to get all the events in one call?
The app runs every x hours with a cron job and I need each time the event array for the given time range.

Comment: What is the response you're getting from the `calendar.events.list({...})` call?

Comment: ```  data:
   { kind: 'calendar#events',
     etag: '"3ccgdfgdstdkghbdsc0g"',
     summary: 'events',
     description: 'Sync events',
     updated: '2019-12-23T15:25:09.895Z',
     timeZone: 'Asia',
     accessRole: 'owner',
     defaultReminders: [],
     nextSyncToken: '***___***',
     items: [] }```@RafaGuillermo

Comment: Shouldn't `pageToken = await eventlist.data.nextPageToken` be inside the `while` loop?